# An issue with ParallelTable

Tags: list-manipulation, interpolation, syntax, parallelization

Consider a function

```
function[x_,y_,method_,distr_]:=NIntegrate[distr[x,y,z,t],{z,zmin[x,y],zmax[x,y]},{t,tmin[z,x,y],tmax[z,x,y]},Method->method]
```

Here, `distr` is some function, while `zmin/zmax, tmin/tmax` explicitly define the domain of the integration.

I want to make a table with rows `{x,y,function[x,y,"AdaptiveMonteCarlo",Distr1]}`. I run two test tables - Table and ParallelTable:

```
table1=Flatten[Table[{x,yval,function[x,yval,"AdaptiveMonteCarlo",Distr1]},{x,xmin,xmax,0.1}],{2,1}]
table2=Flatten[ParallelTable[{x,yval,function[x,yval,"AdaptiveMonteCarlo",Distr1]},{x,xmin,xmax,0.1}],{2,1}]
```

table evaluates normally. table2 has problems. During the first evaluation, Mathematica stucks. After aborting and running the evaluation the second time, it starts displaying errors

```
NIntegrate::inumr: 
   The integrand 1.41996 <<1>> has evaluated to non-numerical values for all
     sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}.
```

and sometimes stucks after that, while sometimes returns some strange values of the integral (typically equal to zero, which is the function-specific values, but sometimes the true result). Could you please tell me how to avoid this problem?

P.S. Please find a code reproducing the problem: https://pastebin.com/raw/hwyVTNEQ. The relevant integral is `integral1`. To launch the code, a file with data is needed (it is required for defining `DoubleDistrMother` function); please find a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2uybpnegz1wtfjz/spectrum.txt?dl=0). It should be downloaded in the notebook's directory.

The tables showing the problem, `table1, table2`, are placed at the bottom of the code. **Note that `ParallelTable` fails to work only with the interpolation of the data (the function `DoubleDistrMother`), but it works with the toy function `DoubleDistrMother1` (`table3` in the code)**. However, I can't manage this problem. The problem remains even if I call `integral1` at fixed point x,y (`table4`).

Comment: You might want to have a look at `DistributeDefinitions`

Comment: Can you add (sample) values for xmin , xmax , Distr1, so we can run your code?

Comment: @MarcoB : I may send a notebook with the code. It is huge (some definitions are required). However, because of an unknown reason, I cannot reproduce the problem for any shorter code. I will try to construct as short notebook as possible.

Comment: @JohnTaylor don’t attach a notebook though. A notebook possibly contains executable code etc and it is unsafe to open such files from unknown sources. Instead copy your code out and sahre it as plain text in a pastebin (https://pastebin.com/).

Comment: @MarcoB : Thanks for the suggestion. I have added the code and a link to a required file.

Comment: The errors are from the code inspection done by `ParallelTable`.  They are not from executing the integrals during the construction of the table. In other words, ignore the errors. -- The first error (I get) is from `NIntegrate[
 DoubleDistrMotherTemp[th, eMother], {th, 0, \[Pi]}, {eMother, 
  MM[Mother], EMothermax[th]}, 
 Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"]`, comes from inspecting/evaluating the definition of `DoubleDistrMother`. Ask WRI what they think.

Comment: @MichaelE2 : but the output of the ParallelTable is wrong. Also, it works very slowly (this problem may be a side problem, but...).

Comment: The output I get looked similar to table1, and I assumed the small differences were due to randomness.

Comment: @MichaelE2 : excuse me, there was an extra spacing in the code from the link, and it luckily removed the problem (although it was just a misprint and had nothing to do with the resolution). I have removed it, now the problem exists.